# EventFlow NETCore 8 - ReadModelByIdQuery invalid parsing data from database

Tags: .net-core, event-sourcing, event-flow

I have a WebApi with EventFlow. It works fine on .NET Core 2.1, but I upgraded it to .NET 8. And there is a problem. When I try to use ReadModelByIdQuery app throws InvalidOperationException. It looks like SqlClient cannot find CorrelationId column, but when I use this on .NET 2.1, it works fine. Have someone any idea about it?

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: Error parsing column 6 (CorrelationId=CH - String)
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SqlGuidCaster' from assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeWorkarounds.SqlGuidCtor(Byte[] value, Boolean ignored)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValueInternal(SqlBuffer value, Byte tdsType, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(Int32 i)
   at Deserialize5ef26d5d-2eb7-4a7d-9c32-0119a057d718(IDataReader)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value)
   at Deserialize5ef26d5d-2eb7-4a7d-9c32-0119a057d718(IDataReader)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command)
   at EventFlow.Sql.Connections.SqlConnection`3.<>c__DisplayClass16_0`1.<<WithConnectionAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at EventFlow.Core.TransientFaultHandler`1.TryAsync[T](Func`2 action, Label label, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventFlow.Sql.Connections.SqlConnection`3.QueryAsync[TResult](Label label, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String sql, Object param)
   at EventFlow.MsSql.ReadStores.MssqlReadModelStore`1.GetAsync(String id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventFlow.Queries.ReadModelByIdQueryHandler`2.ExecuteQueryAsync(ReadModelByIdQuery`1 query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventFlow.Queries.QueryProcessor.ProcessAsync[TResult](IQuery`1 query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApplicationforSG.Controllers.DictionaryController.GetById(String id)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Program.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddEventFlow(opt =>
 {
     opt.AddAspNetCore();
     opt.Configure(c =>
     {
         c.ThrowSubscriberExceptions = true;
         c.IsAsynchronousSubscribersEnabled = true;
     });
     opt.ConfigureMsSql(MsSqlConfiguration.New
         .SetConnectionString(connectionString)
         .SetTransientRetryCount(2));
     opt.AddDefaults(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
     opt.UseConsoleLog();
     opt.UseMssqlEventStore();  
     opt.UseMssqlReadModel<DictionaryEntryReadModel>();   
     opt.RegisterServices(r =>
     {
         r.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ISearchableReadModelStore<>), typeof(EfSearchableReadStore<>));
         r.Register(x => new EmployeeVerificationRequestReadModelLocator());
     });

 });
```

The ReadModel Class

```
 public class DictionaryEntryReadModel : IReadModel,
     IAmReadModelFor<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryCreatedEvent>,
     IAmReadModelFor<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryRemovedEvent>,
     IAmReadModelFor<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryEditedEvent>
 {
     [MsSqlReadModelIdentityColumn]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
     [Key]
     [MaxLength(52)]
     public string AggregateId { get; set; }

     [MsSqlReadModelVersionColumn] 
     public int Version { get; set; }

     public string CustomId { get; set; }
     public DictionaryType EntryType { get; set; }
     public string EntryValue { get; set; }
     public string EntryRegExp { get; set; }
     public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    

     public void Apply(IReadModelContext context,
         IDomainEvent<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryCreatedEvent> domainEvent)
     {
         AggregateId = domainEvent.AggregateIdentity.Value;
         CustomId = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.CustomId;
         EntryType = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.EntryType;
         EntryValue = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.EntryValue;
         EntryRegExp = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.EntryRegExp;
         CorrelationId = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.CorrelationId;
     }

     public void Apply(IReadModelContext context, IDomainEvent<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryRemovedEvent> domainEvent)
     {
         context.MarkForDeletion();
     }

     public void Apply(IReadModelContext context, IDomainEvent<DictionaryEntryAggregate, DictionaryEntryId, DictionaryEntryEditedEvent> domainEvent)
     {
         CustomId = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.CustomId;
         EntryValue = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.EntryValue;
         EntryRegExp = domainEvent.AggregateEvent.EntryRegExp;
     }
 }
```

Table

```
TABLE [dbo].[ReadModel-DictionaryEntry](
    [AggregateId] [nvarchar](52) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntryType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntryValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EntryRegExp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [timestamp] NULL,
```

csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="EventFlow.DependencyInjection" Version="0.83.4713"/>
<PackageReference Include="EventFlow.AspNetCore" Version="0.83.4713"/>
<PackageReference Include="EventFlow.MsSql" Version="0.83.4713"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.2"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: did you try to upgrade System.Data.SqlClient ?

Comment: I've edited my post and added csproj packages. SqlClient is in EventFlow package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0`, update your package to latest version of `System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.6` - if issues is not resolved as suggested according to this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86969) (Btw I don't think that they have resolved it and I don't thing that they plan in System.Data.SqlClient).

Next solution would be to uninstall `System.Data.SqlClient` and use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.5` - on this [GitHub raised issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1930) they will fix it in version 5.2.0 which should be published by the end of this month.

Comment: I update System.Data.SqlClient to 4.8.6 and it works :) Thank you for your help.